# Shaking Music player

Tags: android, controller, android-sensors

i posted an question on stackoverflow but nobody can answer me. it might, i couldn't say my question very well. now i try to say it better. I want a chunck of andrid codeto detect shake; but not normal shake, an slap. i saw a music palyer(sensor music palyer) on google play store that can detect slap and change music when you put your phone in your pocket.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zgui.musicshaker

can any body help me detect slap. the hard part of this code is detect difference between normal motion or shake , ... whith slap that is small hit

thanks

Comment: What's your actual question ? How to implement actions on android while shaking device ?

Comment: no no. let see the screenshot below  https://lh5.ggpht.com/cayz5vw3L01jn9c3VFRjPiDRRv5-kOYHYUfHnCHyeH-5dOxSxfocWySpwrhxODxTOLLt=h900-rw  in pocket state you put your phone in your pocket and with some hit, you can change music. my question is too how can i make difference between shake and pocket mode while i am walking for example because when you walking, your phone is moving two. was this player use accelerometer sensor?